# How do I configure Wordpress to update automatically?

Tags: updates, apache2, wordpress

I installed apache2, mysql, php5 and phpmyadmin

Now i moved my old Wordpress installtion from my htdocs Folder under Windows in my /var/www/ Folder under Ubuntu.

Now, when i want to update some of my plugins i have to put in the Servername, Username and Password.

That never happens under Windows. Under Windows after clicking Update, it automatically updated all without the need of typing the server and so on.

What do i have to type in, so the update will take place normally?

Comment: I solved the Problem. I've just set the owner of the wordpress Folder to www-data by using this comman sudo chown -R www-data directory/

Comment: could you post an answer to your own question? Please ping me and I'll upvote the answer. This will move it off the `unanswered question` list. Thank you.